# Белый экран после того как добавил php файл

Tags: php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Калькулятор индекса тела</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"> 
        <form accept="" method="post" name="form">
            <h2>Калькулятор индекса тела</h2>
            <p>
                Ваш пол:
                <input type="radio" name="pol" value="m" />M
                <input type="radio" name="pol" value="w" />Ж 
            </p>
            <p>Ваш рост:<input type="text" name="rost"> M</p>
            <p>Ваш вес:<input type="text" name="ves"> кг</p>

        </form>

            <input onclick="Ma()" type="submit" name="schet" value="Рассчитать индекс массы">
            <br><br>
            <input type="button" name="" value="Очистить" onclick="this.form.reset()" />
        
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> 

```
<?php 

    if (isset($_POST['rost']) && isset($_POST['ves']) && isset($_POST['pol'])){

        $rost = $_POST['rost'];
        $ves = $_POST['ves'];
        $pol = $_POST['pol'];
    
    }

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "massa");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `massa` (`rost`,`ves`,`pol`) VALUES ('$rost','$ves','$pol')";
?>[![Просто белый экран, как это исправить? ][1]][1]
```

Comment: Во-первых, включите отображение ошибок и увидите fatal error, во-вторых, нельзя просто взять и вставить данные с инпутов в базу, надо их всегда валидировать.

Comment: massa - это имя таблицы. А имя базы?

Comment: @DrMcSheen massa это имя таблицы и бд